# Bootstrap responsive navbar menu giving me problems

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

First problem: The hamburger menu icon is not showing up.  If you hover to the right of the navbar in the mobile view you will find the link though.

Second problem: When the menu expands, it does not start under the brand img.  I would like the dropdown menu to be centered below the brand.

Can anyone help out with this?

http://www.bootply.com/EdFJvLZyma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hamburger is not showing up because the `.icon-bar` class does not have a background color. Adding the following will make the hamburger appear.

```
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #000;
}
```

And the following should move the menu under the brand

```
.navbar-collapse {
    margin-top: 50px;
}

ul.nav.navbar-nav.navbar-right {
    width: 110px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: The background color is working.  Also, after messing with some margins, that is working for my navbar on my iPhone.  But, when I resize my chrome browser, it is really off.

Comment: @Jay Sorry for the delay. I've updated my answer with something that should fix it for you! :)